# Как защищаются платные библиотеки от нелегального распространения?

Tags: алгоритм, dll

Подскажите, а как осуществляется защита платных библиотек от пиратства?

Например, купил я какую-то библиотеку и что мне мешает ее слить в интернет?

Comment: Например, что вам мешает проникнуть в чужую квартиру? :) Вот примерно то же самое...

Comment: Очень часто используются не технические, а административные методы. Если использование библиотеки без лицензии запрещено законом, немногие захотят заработать крупный штраф или даже сесть в тюрьму, если нарушение вскроется.

Answer (score 0):

Обычный метод защиты - это регистрация использования на конкретной рабочей станции (аппаратная часть) в конкретной программной среде. На основании некоторых идентифицирующих признаков из них формируется единый идентификатор системы, и создаётся ключ, который соответствует именно этой совокупности признаков. При переносе на другую систему единый идентификатор получится другим, и не будет соответствовать ключу. Ключ может быть как чисто ключом данных, так и аппаратным. Самая простая версия этой методы - использование серийного номера (как, например, было в Windows), т.е. регистрация легитимности просто по факту знания оператором регистрационного ключа.

Либо используется аппаратный ключ, осуществляющий некоторые функции по приведению библиотеки в рабочее состояние (например, дешифрование некоторых блоков кода и/или данных) без привязки к оборудованию - тогда библиотека работает на том рабочем месте, где установлен ключ.